# Missing number treated as zero in eqnarray*

Tags: equations

The following `eqnarray*` environment

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
[v,v] &=&  0\\
[v,v+0] &=& 0\\
[v,v] + [v,0] &=& 0\\
0 + [v,0] &=& 0\\
[v,0] &=& 0\\
[0,v] = -[v,0] = -(0) = 0\\
Maka didapat [v,0] = 0 = [0,v].
\end{eqnarray*}
```

gives the error

```
Missing number treated as zero
```

Comment: You might want to use the align-environment. See also: http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/

Comment: so if i cant use eqnarray*?

Comment: @sigur, i delete $, and still same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens when a line following `\\` starts with `[` because `LaTeX` thinks there is an optional argument. To prevent it, you can put an empty group `{}` before `[`. Also, I think the last line belongs outside the array, and another dollar sign is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*} 
[v,v] &=& 0\\    
{}[v,v+0] &=& 0\\  
{}[v,v] + [v,0] &=& 0\\ 
0 + [v,0] &=& 0\\   
{}[v,0] &=& 0\\      
{}[0,v] = -[v,0] = -(0) = 0     
\end{eqnarray*}
Maka didapat $[v,0] = 0 = [0,v]$.
\end{document}
```

Finally, as @mcwise points out in the comments, use of the `eqnarray` and `eqnarray*` environments is not recommended. Primarily, this is because the spacing is inconsistent with all other maths environments, but in fact the problem you encountered is another `eqnarray` drawback. Instead, you can use the `align` and `align*` environments from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), and then the only requirement when `[` follows `\\` is that they appear on separate lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}                                                              
[v,v]     &= 0\\     
[v,v+0] &= 0\\    
[v,v] + [v,0] &= 0\\    
0 + [v,0] &= 0\\   
[v,0]   &= 0\\         
[0,v]   &= -[v,0] = -(0) = 0                                              
\end{align*}
Maka didapat $[v,0] = 0 = [0,v]$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `align` or `align*` there's no need to protect the `[` so long as it's in a different input line than ``\\``

Comment: @egreg --- Thanks; I didn't know that.

Comment: my professor just told me the other day about why not to use eqnarray and pointed me to this document :)